# classes error android studio 1.0.1 in gradle assemblerelease

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexRelease'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\Hotline4all\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\21.1.1\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\Hotline4all\AndroidStudioProjects\NaviFirm\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\release\classes-9aafb64c1dbda8b053c0fc7341f345d6468240b4.jar C:\Users\Hotline4all\AndroidStudioProjects\NaviFirm\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\6.1.71\classes.jar
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: could you explain more and add some code ??

Comment: Solve by updating SDK to 24.0.2